# knockout ko is undefined using requirejs and typescript

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, typescript

My typescript files generates the following output, but i get a ko is undefined in my AppViewModel. Any pointers on how i can solve this is welcome. The visual studio solution with typescript is here: https://github.com/s093294/typescript-knockout

#### /Scripts/App/config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/Scripts/App/',
    paths: {
        'jQuery': '/scripts/jquery-1.9.1',
        'knockout': '/scripts/knockout-2.2.1.debug',
        'AppViewModel': '/Scripts/ViewModels/AppViewModel'
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    shim: {
        jQuery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'knockout': {
            deps: [
                "jQuery"
            ],
            exports: 'ko'
        },
        'AppViewModel': {
            deps: [
                'knockout'
            ]
        }
    }
});
require([
    'AppViewModel'
], function (avm) {
    var viewmodel = new avm.AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
    alert('hello world - SUCCESS');
});
```

#### /Scripts/ViewModels

```
define(["require", "exports", "knockout"], function(require, exports) { // I would like ko to be in the function handle, but typescript cant do this. But it should be in the global scope also right?
    var AppViewModel = (function () {
        function AppViewModel() {
            this.title = ko.observable();
            this.title('My Sample');
        }
        AppViewModel.prototype.setTitle = function (title) {
            this.title(title);
        };
        return AppViewModel;
    })();
    exports.AppViewModel = AppViewModel;    
})
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />    
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    Did you get a hello world?
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>

    <script data-main="/Scripts/App/config" type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hacked it in the following way, but would like any comments if people can find a better way.

```
require(['knockout','AppViewModel'], (koo,avm) => {
    (<any>window).ko = koo;
    var viewmodel = new avm.AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
    alert('hello world - SUCCESS');

});
```

Comment: Did you find a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Yes, with newest Typescript everything works out the box with type definitions from nuget ect. Try search abit more and if you fail to find a working solution you can send an email to pks@s-innovations.net and I will try to find an example in the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading knockout first, it looks like your viewmodel is a compiled TypeScript module. Loading knockout manually instead of a dependency may give you more control.

```
require([
    'knockout',
    'AppViewModel'
], function (ko, avm) {
    var viewmodel = new avm.AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
    alert('hello world - SUCCESS');
});
```

Also make sure to remove knockout as a dep of AppViewModel

Comment: It makes the ko avalible in the config yes. But not in the AppViewModel. ko is not being defined in the global scope.

Comment: The loading timing was my issue. I had both KO and KO.Mapping in the same bundle, and it was failing. I split the bundles apart and it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for my original answer but have you tried capitalizing the /Scripts/ reference in your config.js file?

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about a runtime error vs a compile time error. It looks like he has posted the compiled javascript meaning it built fine.

Comment: Thats my own question you link to, and it do not solve the problem. This question was made with a minimal solution to the problem i have, that ko is not defined. Please be more specific about what is needed to get the sample working.

Comment: @dmck is correct. Compiling work fine, its a runtime error that ko is not defined in the global scope.